# How do I enable page caching in Yii? It's not working

Tags: php, caching, yii, yii2

How do I enable page caching in Yii? I followed the documentation, but it's not working.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-page.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html#pagecache

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'pageCache' => [
              'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
              'only' => ['index'],
              'duration' => 10*60,
              'variations' => [
                  \Yii::$app->language,
              ],
```

`Server response`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 01:25:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.2a DAV/2 PHP/5.6.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.7
Set-Cookie: ...cookies...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4750
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Notice there is no `Cache-Control:max-age=` or `Expires:` heading. If I change the class to `xPageCache` then it does fail with an error, so it's reading the settings.

Comment: Can you expand on "not working" for us? How do you know it is not working? What are you looking for in the response headers?

Comment: Is it worth taking out the `only` temporarily to see if that is the problem?

Comment: @halfer Ok I commented out that line, and commented out the `.htaccess`, and reloaded the page, but it's still not sending any `Cache-Control` headers.

Comment: Why do you think yii must send you cache headers? This is a web-server job (apache2, nginx). Yii just caches the content of the page and save to file, db or memcached (depends on config).

Comment: OK, I'd next dig into the plugin to see if it is being called at all (I expect it is, and it is failing on some internal conditionals). Also, try taking out the `variations` temporarily in case that's causing a problem.

Comment: @AxelPAL So you are saying that page caching doesn't save in the browser, and it only saves it on the server? How can I verify that it's working and doing anything?

Comment: @Chloe, may be you should point the dependancy for your PageCache? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-pagecache.html#$dependency-detail

Answer (score 0):

It was working. I had to update the design of the page and it would not show the changes after reload. It seems to be a server side rendering cache, not a HTTP browser cache. So it saves rendering the page, but not the request/response to the server.